# Compare element height to browser height

Tags: jquery

I want to check that if an element is less than the browser length minus two other elements using jquery this is the code i currently have

```
<script>

        var browser = $(window).height();
        var post = $('#PostContainer').height();
        var hf = $('#Header').height() + $('#Footer').height();
        var remainder = browser - hf;

        if (post < remainder) {
            $('#Footer').css({position: 'absolute', bottom: '0px'});
        } else {
            $('#Footer').css({position: 'relative'});
        }

    </script>
```

but it doesn't work so how would i do it?

Comment: Does it work? If not, then explain how it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery lacks a [document ready event handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), so it's not triggering... wrap your existing code with the the following:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Your code here
});
```

Comment: yes i did forget that thanks for it but it still doesn't work

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Have your tried to console.log() the values to find out if they equal what's expected?